# Different size of files on the disk and in MS SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

As an exercise I've inserted some image files into MS SQL database. They are occupying approx. 3.9GB on disk but when I look at data increase from storage size on volume where database is located I see increase of 1008MiB only. Can someone explain why it's like that? I have actually no experience in SQL and this test with SQL was just to test storage under the database, not db itself.

This is how I insert images:

```
insert into graphics (id, picture) SELECT '9974', BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'F:\dist\img_1643140662.349239.jpg', Single_Blob) as picture
```

When looking at database space usage with SQL queries I see that database grown by 985MB.

On the other hand table size is over 1GB... (before insert it was 0KB)

[image: Table size]

Can someone please explain this in simple words why there is different info in each place?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's reading all of your files in. While SQL Server has options for row compression and page compression that's unlikely to shrink JFIF data at all and certainly not by 75%. Have you tried exporting all of your image data back out to files? How big is the result? How many files are missing?

Comment: Also, what is the data type of the `picture` column? `varbinary(max)` or something else?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning good point, I'm trying to insert 10000 rows but I can only find 2348... picture column data type is 'image'. Any idea why not all rows are inserted? I don't get any error message. Maybe there is a limit of buffer size for db or other hard limit set by default? total size of db is 1TB so there is plenty of space available.

Comment: Since you're in early days of learning SQL Server you're probably unaware that you should no longer be using the `image` data type - it has been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. Ref: [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) _IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead._

Comment: The `image` data type itself is unlikely to be the cause of the issue here, though. More likely there are file system ACLs preventing the account under which SQL Server executes from reading all of the files, but I would expect error messages regarding that.

Comment: thank you for your hints regarding image datatype - as you assumed I was unaware of this :) I think I found the issue and in fact there was an error message. Transaction log is getting full as there is no commit and I'm trying to put 10000 rows, each with separate insert command so transaction log of 1gb is not enough to handle this...